# Clang: ARM Cross compiling C++ with Threads

Tags: c++, clang, cross-compiling, clang++

I want to compile this simple code to run on ARM architecture (an Android smartphone):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

static const int num_threads = 10;

void call_from_thread(int tid) {
    std::cout << "Launched by thread " << tid << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::thread t[num_threads];
    //Launch a group of threads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i] = std::thread(call_from_thread, i);
    }
    std::cout << "Launched from the main\n";
    //Join the threads with the main thread
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using Clang, I can compile this program to native architecture (x86) with the following statement:

```
# clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
```

But, the cross compiling statement return an error:

```
# clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread -target armv7a-none-linux-eabi
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Could someone please help me or give me some tips?

Comment: Have you installed an appropriate toolchain for ARM?  See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33111276/327083

Comment: @J... ECC seems to be dead now, is there a way to do that now in 2023?